# Erro ao injetar repositório framework em .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, injeção-de-dependência

Estou tendo problemas em tentando fazer injeção de dependência de um repositório .NET framework e uma API .NET Core e esta ocorrendo o problema abaixo:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DataAccessRf.Repositorio.CotistaRepositorio' while attempting to activate 'EMP.PainelCotista.WebService.Services.CotistaService'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
```

Onde o repositorio "DataAccessRf.Repositorio.CotistaRepositorio" esta em .NET framework e "EMP.PainelCotista.WebService.Services.CotistaService" é um webservice em .NET core.

Segue o código da instância:

> private readonly CotistaRepositorio _cotistaRepositorio;
>
> ```
>     public CotistaService(CotistaRepositorio cotistaRepositorio)
>     {
>         _cotistaRepositorio = cotistaRepositorio;
>     }
>
>     public Cotista Authenticate(string email, string senha)
>     {
>         Cotista cotista =  _cotistaRepositorio.AuthCotista(email, senha);
>         if (cotista == null)
>             throw new AppException("Dados de login incorretos");
>
>         return cotista;
>     }
> ```

Teriam alguma sugestão ou dica para resolver este problema.
Obrigado

Comment: apresente o código

Comment: Leandro Angelo já coloquei a parte da instancia

Comment: essa parte do código não diz nada sobre como você está injetando a dependência, por gentileza fornecer mais informações

Comment: A questão é essa Lucas. Nunca fiz um injeção do framework para o core. Poderia dizer o que é preciso fazer no startup.cs para realizar essa chamada?

Comment: já adicionei a linha services.AddTransient<CotistaRepositorio, CotistaRepositorio>(); no startup.cs o erro mudou. Sera que pode ser alguma configuração do mysql?

Comment: Acredito que sua resposta se encontra na própria documentação da Microsoft.
Link: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: esse overload que você ta usando é pra quando se possui uma interface e uma implementação, como você não está usando interface o certo seria:  services.AddTransient<CotistaRepositorio>() apenas, como não tem mais do seu código não posso falar muito além disso

Comment: Futuramente para facilitar você poderia utilizar o scrutor para injetar as classes conforme vai desenvolvendo para não esquecer de injetar algo. https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/